# Self referencing fields in protobuf messages

Tags: java, .net, protocol-buffers

Is it ok to have message like this?

```
message A {
  required int64 some_number = 1;
  // .... some more fields
  optional A sub_a = 123;
}
```

The reason is my current protocol stores set of A directly, and wrapping A's in another message will lead to massive conversions of stored data.

2.2.0 protoc compiles it ok. 
Can this make any problems with serialization/deserialization, and is it supported by protobuf-net.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is a perfectly fine definition, and *should* work in any implementation (including protobuf-net); are you seeing any problem? HOWEVER! you might want to consider the computational impact of serialization - in particular, to serialize a sub-message, the size of the sub-messages needs to be known ***first***. A deeply recursive method (as necessitated by this linked-list) may cause some issues.

Is there any reason this can't be just a `repeated` message instead? that would *by far* be my preference.

Comment: current protocol is sending and storing A messages, not wrapper B with repeated A field. Changing protocol is much more work then just adding field to A. e.g. in B case i will need to convert all stored data to new message types or support both A and B messages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about protobuf-net, but it *should* be absolutely fine. I suspect that if it *doesn't* work in protobuf-net, Marc would count that as a bug, and fix it... that's certainly the attitude I'd take in my C# port :)

(Realistically, I can't easily see how it would be a problem... it's not like messages are going to be represented by structs, where the recursion would be an issue.)

It should be pretty easy to test - I suggest you give it a try with a small message, and see if you run into any problems. All you've really got to do is create a message and test whether you can serialize and deserialize it correctly, possibly between different platforms.

EDIT: Obviously you need to make sure there are no actual cycles in terms of the messages themselves...

Comment: i tested it with google's implementation, not protobuf-net side which i don't have much access to.

Comment: @float_dublin: Surely if you're going to use protobuf-net, you should have access to it shouldn't you?

Comment: i publish proto files and some docs to describe byte level protocol. protobuf-net side is made not by me. And adding new features without breaking old versions of software is the best thing i like about protobuf.